# How to use Kivy 1.9.0 with existing Anaconda3 2.3.0

Tags: kivy, anaconda

I'm going to write Python3 programs and i want to use Kivy 1.9.0 in Anaconda 2.3.0 in windows, any guid and any help can be useful, these are two awesome package that help a programmer to easily install and use many powerful features of Python3 and useful packages included in Anaconda 3 with best GUI building library of Pyhton, Kivy. i think this will be useful for many other new programmers to start easily to create a "Hello World!" program to "Advanced World!" program. thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why you vote negative? I and many new programmers that i'm working with them need this answer. if you don't no answer don't give negative vote.

Comment: I wrote a few line of description for new other programmers to know what are Kivy and Anaconda. my question is just in Title.

Comment: are you asking how to install kivy or are you asking how to use kivy? read here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Kivy is a separate library and anaconda have most useful libraries separatly too, in normal form impossible to use anaconda's libraries in kivy or use Kivy in Anaconda. We are looking for a way to use both Anaconda and Kivy in one place like (Pycharm IDE 5).

Comment: Install/Copy/Build/Extract we don't how, but a simple way to have both Anaconda's libraries and Kivy in same place to use "import" in a Python IDE together.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, follow these directions carefully: http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation. Or try by way of the appropriate binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy. Note to forum mods: this could probably be closed as a duplicate. See "site:stackoverflow how to install kivy"

Comment: I installed Kivy in a folder and I installed Anaconda3 in another drive, i can use both separately but i can't use Kivy when i'm using Anaconda3 in Pycharm IDE

Comment: That's not very descriptive. "kivy in a folder" and "Anaconda3 in another drive", how could you expect someone to be able to help you with that information? It is likely that your Pycharm Project interpreter is pointing to the wrong place. You should edit your post to show what you have tried, in detail, and then describe with some precision, what is not working. e.g. what have you tried from the kivy installation guide, and what is not working after following that?